# G++ wrong ELF CLASS Error

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, makefile

I was trying to compile a C++ program on Fedora 15 x64. And got the error:

```
./game: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory.
```

I read somewhere that all I need to do is install `glibc.i686`

I installed that and now another error is coming even after using the "-m64" option with g++

```
error while loading shared libraries: libplayer_1.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Here's what my makefile looks like:

```
CONC_INC = ./include \
            -I../include
APP = ./src/player_1.cxx


All :  
    g++ -m64 -Wall -g -fPIC -I$(CONC_INC) -c $(APP)
    g++ -m64 -shared -W1 -o libplayer1.so.1.0 *.o
    cp libplayer1.so.1.0 ../lib/libplayer_1.so.1.0
    ln -sf ../lib/libplayer_1.so.1.0 ../lib/libplayer_1.so
    ln -sf ../lib/libplayer_1.so.1.0 ../lib/libplayer_1.so.1
clean: 
    \rm -f *.so.* *.o
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original issue that you had suggests that `./game` is a 32-bit dynamically-linked executable, which was failing to run because the 32-bit dynamic linker (`/lib/ld-linux.so.2`) wasn't installed; installing the 32-bit `glibc` package fixed that.

If `./game` is a 32-bit executable which requires `libplayer_1.so` as a dynamic library, it's not going to work if `libplayer_1.so` is 64-bit, which is what the new error is telling you.

Try building the library as 32-bit instead (`-m32` rather than `-m64`).